# How do I use MixMeister BPM analyzer and keep the tags on my non-mp3 files?

Tags: mp3, m4a, id3-tag

So I was hoping to find songs listed under the same BPM in my library. That's when I came across this BPM analyzer, so I decided to analyze all my songs, problem is about half of my songs are ".M4A" (AAC codec) and the program only accepts ".MP3" and I've converted all the M4A's to MP3's and tagged all the MP3's with the analyzer, but the convertor I used didn't keep the other tags from the old files (which I still have). What is the best options for me to put both the BPM tags and all the other ID3 tags onto either the MP3 or the M4A files? Should I reconvert all the M4A's with a new convertor that keeps the tags and then analyze them all? Or is there an application that can combine M4A and MP3 tags onto one of the files? As you might have guess my library is too big to go through them one at a time. I'm currently hovering at over 6000 songs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just convert all my music using Foobar2000 which as it turns out keeps the tags intact during the conversion, and from there re-tag the BPM for all the music using the analyzer because moving the tags would have been more of a hassle. It took a day or two, but it was faster than other methods would have been. If anyone wants to suggest whether it would be more suitable to keep all my music in AAC or OGG feel free to give me your reasons in the comments to this post because I may or may not be leaving them as MP3's.